# apple enterprise account

Tags: iphone, itunes, enterprise, account

my client has apple enterprise account.
apple itunes reject my account as it is enterprise account.
Can anybody diff bet this account type, i.e. developer account and enterprise account.
also how can i efficiently use apple enterprise account.
and from where i can load app using this account as itunes refuses.

thanks
gopal rathod.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [we are not customer support for your favourite company](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't publish an app in the app store with an enterprise account.
The enterprise account is for in-house-deployment only. I.E. apps that are only used by the employees of the company.
So if I understood your question correctly the answer is: Join the iOS Developer Program (non-enterprise).

Apple has a [comparison chart](https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/#compare)

Comment: so how can i load app to iphone/ipad with enterprise account

Comment: Thank you for your answer. so how can i provide app to inhouse customer and one more thing i m getting code signing error while loading app through xcode

Comment: @Matthias Bauch Can i change Apple developer Enterprise Program to normal Apple developer Program (Organization) so that I can submit apps in Appstore.

Comment: Is volunteer consider to be the employee of the company?